# Get WARN related to database and registry indexing in WSO2 ESB5.0.0

Tags: wso2, mariadb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a cluster of WSO2 ESB with 1 manager node and more than 5 worker nodes. my database is mariadb with galera. recently I got some WARN in my logs. same as below:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-01-08 13:34:13,537]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter} -  An error occurred while submitting resources for indexing {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to start new registry transaction.
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.beginTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:97)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.beginTransaction(EmbeddedRegistry.java:443)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.getLogs(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2371)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.getLogs(CacheBackedRegistry.java:485)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getLogsInternal(UserRegistry.java:1810)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$3600(UserRegistry.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$37.run(UserRegistry.java:1781)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$37.run(UserRegistry.java:1778)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getLogs(UserRegistry.java:1778)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter.submitResource(ResourceSubmitter.java:119)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter.run(ResourceSubmitter.java:76)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 226,314,205 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 226,299,120 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1281.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2518)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2482)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4796)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.invoke(ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:71)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:153)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.TrapException.invoke(TrapException.java:41)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDatabaseTransaction$ManagedRegistryConnection.setAutoCommit(JDBCDatabaseTransaction.java:1485)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.beginTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:92)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-01-08 13:34:16,541] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.dataaccess.TransactionManager} -  Failed to start new registry transaction. {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.dataaccess.TransactionManager}
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 226,317,209 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 226,302,124 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1281.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2518)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2482)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4796)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.invoke(ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:71)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:153)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.TrapException.invoke(TrapException.java:41)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDatabaseTransaction$ManagedRegistryConnection.setAutoCommit(JDBCDatabaseTransaction.java:1485)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.beginTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.beginTransaction(EmbeddedRegistry.java:443)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.getLogs(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2371)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.getLogs(CacheBackedRegistry.java:485)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getLogsInternal(UserRegistry.java:1810)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$3600(UserRegistry.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$37.run(UserRegistry.java:1781)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$37.run(UserRegistry.java:1778)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getLogs(UserRegistry.java:1778)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter.submitResource(ResourceSubmitter.java:119)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter.run(ResourceSubmitter.java:76)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My datasource config(/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml) is:

```
<datasources-configuration xmlns:svns="http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration">
     <providers>
        <provider>org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader</provider>
    </providers>
    <datasources>
        <datasource>
            <name>REGISTRY_LOCAL1</name>
            <description>The datasource used for registry- local</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://esb:3307/ESB_LocalRegistry_W02?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false</url>
                    <username>esb</username>
                    <password>QCP5SvEWL4</password>
                    <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
        <datasource>
            <name>REGISTRY_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for registry- config/governance</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2RegistryDB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://esb:3307/ESB_ShareRegistry?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false</url>
                    <username>esb</username>
                    <password>QCP5SvEWL4</password>
                    <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
         <datasource>
            <name>WSO2_USER_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2UMDB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://esb:3307/ESB_ShareUser?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false</url>
                    <username>esb</username>
                    <password>QCP5SvEWL4</password>
                    <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
   </datasources>
</datasources-configuration>
```

1. Why do I get these WARNs?
2. How can I fix it?
3. FYI, my services are working properly and there is no error in proxy service calls.